# Rescaling Vertical and Horizontal Axes

Tags: matlab, graph, world-map

I am producing a series of figures of a world map. I wish to rescale the vertical and horizontal axes. At present, the vertical axis is from -80 to 80 (in increments of 20) and the horizontal axis is from 0 to 360 (in increments of 50).

I wish to set the vertical axis to be from -70 to 70 (in increments of 20) and the horizontal axis to be from 0 to 360 (but in increments of 30).

Here is a section of my code for the colour of the map, as well as arranging the colourbar.

```
function custom_map=mycolormap
blues = [linspace(0, 1, 100); 
         linspace(0, 1, 100); 
         linspace(1, 1, 100);]';
reds = [linspace(1, 1, 100);
        linspace(1, 0, 100); 
        linspace(1, 0, 100);]';
custom_map = [blues; reds]; 
caxis([-6,6]);
ylabel(colorbar, 'SSTA (°C)');
```

Comment: `xlim`, `ylim`, `xticks`, `yticks`

Comment: @David xlim[0,360] and ylim[-70,70]? I'm a bit of a novice at using matlab :(

Comment: @David I've tried the xticks and yticks commands, but an error message is displayed

Comment: Type `help xlim` into the command window (or `help` and any other function name) and you will get a nice brief description of the command. Use `xlim` like a normal function, `xlim([-70 70])`.

Comment: @David Regardless of what A and B are, the axes are unchanged when using xlim([A B]) and ylim([A B])

Comment: Are you doing anything else to the axes after setting `xlim`/`ylim`?

Comment: @I set xlim/ylim in a separate function. Should I move it to a different script? It's hard to explain.

Comment: In your custom function try to add `set(gca,'xlim',[-70,70])`, use the same method to change `xtick`, `ytick`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do so using xlim, ylim, xticks and yticks. It seems to me that what you should do is insert the following lines at the end of your function:

```
xMin   = 0;
xMax   = 360;
xStep  = 30;
yMin   = -70;
yMax   = 70;
yStep  = 20;
xlim([xMin, xMax]);      % Sets the limit of the x axis
ylim([yMin, yMax]);      % Sets the limit of the y axis
xticks(xMin:xStep:xMax); % Sets the increments of the x axis
yticks(yMin:yStep:yMax); % Sets the increments of the y axis
```

As far as I've tried this should work. Feel free to follow different naming conventions for naming the variables but it is good practice to avoid magic numbers in your code especially since some of them will appear multiple times.

Hope this helps.